# Can't get the code send by keyboard when press Ctrl+5

Tags: arch-linux, terminal, kde, manjaro, konsole

I'm on KDE, Manjaro.

I set `Ctrl+5` as shortcut for yakuake to `switch to session 5`. But it doesn't work. There is no notifications told me that I made a ambiguous shortcut.

What I found is when I use `showkey` to examine the codes sent by the keyboard when I press `Ctrl+5`, nothing shows.

```
➜  ~ showkey -a

Press any keys - Ctrl-D will terminate this program

1        49 0061 0x31
^@        0 0000 0x00
^[       27 0033 0x1b
^\       28 0034 0x1c
^^       30 0036 0x1e
^_       31 0037 0x1f
^?      127 0177 0x7f
9        57 0071 0x39
0        48 0060 0x30
^D        4 0004 0x04
➜  ~
```

I press `Ctrl+{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0} and`Ctrl+D`to exit`showkey` in order above.

So, it means can't get the code send by keyboard when press Ctrl+5 in yakueke and konsole.

Comment: Just to be clear: You are using `showkey` on the terminal emulated by the terminal emulator that you have configured to filter out that key chord, handle specially, and not pass along to programs.  Yes?

Comment: Hi, @JdeBP YES, I'm using `showkey` on the terminal emulated by the terminal emulator. But, not sure the meaning of `you have configured to filter out that key chord, handle specially, and not pass along to programs`. I have test it on tty, too. Tty works well.

Comment: Actually you do.  It's the second sentence of your question.